# Minimum 1 field is required from 26 field in laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to make a money receipt in laravel. I have 26 input fields. It's tough to declare one by one validation with the condition. Is it possible to required minimum 1 field? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rules = [
    'a_field' => 'required_without_all:b_field,c_field',
    'b_field' => 'required_without_all:a_field,c_field',
    'c_field' => 'required_without_all:a_field,b_field',
];
$message = [
    'a_field' => 'The a is required when none of other fields are present.',
    'b_field' => 'The b is required when none of other fields are present.',
    'c_field' => 'The c is required when none of other fields are present.',
];
```

for too many inputs

```
$fields = collect(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);

$rules = $fields->mapWithKeys(function ($field) use ($fields) {
    return [
        $field => 'required_without_all:' . $fields->reject(function ($item) use ($field) {
            return $item == $field;
        })->implode(',')
    ];
})->toArray();
```

Comment: do i need to add 26 lines for this validation? is there any other shortest way? like using array or anything else?

Comment: Is this helps to you ?

Comment: i don't know about desine custom rules.. can you please give me the way to define this method in validation. please?

Comment: This is not custom rule

Comment: I always use this code... 
`$this->validate($request, [
            'field' => 'required',
        ]);`

Comment: then what would be the way for your codes? Can you please edit your code with full function? please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213250/discussion-between-tariqul-anik-and-omer-yilmaz).